# How to query mongodb documents with one same fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have multiple mongodb documents with some different fields but with one same field name as an identifier. How do I query the different documents using the one identical field? For example, the following documents all have a field for "name" but no other fields in common.

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "dave123", "gender" : "male"}
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "dave123", "age" : 23}
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "an567",  "gender" : "male"}
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "an567", "age" : 21}
```

If I wanted to query everyone who is a male and is 23, how would I go about that? The following code doesn't return anything because there are no documents with both fields. Rather, there are two separate documents with one matching field each.

```
df.collections.find({$and: [{"gender" : "male"}, {"age" : 23}]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to prepare the data first followed by [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) in a aggregate query.

Something like

```
db.collections.aggregate([
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$name",
    "gender":{"$push":"$gender"},
    "age":{"$push":"$age"}
  }},
  {"$match":{"gender":"male","age":23}}
])
```

Comment: When I try this, I get null values in the gender and age fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `gender` and `age` together in the document, you just can't have any result with your query

Comment: So there is no way to query like how I want to?

Comment: I think you have to rethink you schema. As I see in your example,  you have one document with gender field, and another with age field, but with the same name. Why did you not store the value in the same document ?

Comment: That is just an example. I am dealing with large amounts of data and wanted it to be more structured.